# Trying to display problems one at a time.

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an simple math test that has 10 problems. They have to display one at a time. I have hit a roadblock and I'm not sure how to move forward from here. I made a submit button and I figured I could just load the next question onClick load but it's a little more complicated than I thought.Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Interactive Math Worksheet</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var mathProblem = new Array();
var carryOver = document.getElementById("carry");
var correct = 0;
var wrong = 2;
// writing the problem 10 times
function writeProblem(){
    for (var i=1; i<11; i++){
        num1 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+1);
        num2 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+1);
        document.getElementById("top"+i).innerHTML = num1;
        document.getElementById("bottom"+i).innerHTML = "+" + num2;
        mathProblem[i] = num1 + num2;
        document.forms["problem"+i]["answer"+i].value = "";
}
}
function submitAnswer(){
    var i=0;

    for (i=1;i<11;x++) {
        if (document.forms["problem"+i]["answer"+i].value == mathProblem[i]) {
        return true;

    }
    else if(isNaN (document.forms["problem"+i]["answer"+i].value)){
            alert("This is not a spelling test please use numbers");
            return false;
    }

}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="writeProblem()">
<h2>Practicing Your Pluses!</h2>

<form name="problem1">
<input type="text" size="1" name="carry1"><br/> 
<label id="top1"></label><br />
<label id="bottom1"></label><br /><hr width="60px" align="left"/>
<input type="text" size="3" name="answer1">
</form><br/>

<input type="button" onClick="submitAnswer()" value="Submit Answers"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you sending the results to? A server? Can't you do the problem selection there? That would make more sense IMHO.

Comment: I was trying to do it all in HTML i could use prompts but it looks bad doing it that way. I don't have to use a <form> tag.

Comment: forms have an action attribute that sends data with a http GET or POST method ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/HTML/Element/form))...

Answer (score 0):

I think This above code gives this Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Because in your code writeProblem() function has mistake, by the time the function call document read only the element with id "top1" another ids are not there but you are repeting the loop 11 times, so change the onload function body according to the standards of Javascript

I have updated the code please check once [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbandi/3vFXw/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Interactive Math Worksheet</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var mathProblem = new Array();
var carryOver = document.getElementById("carry");
var correct = 0;
var wrong = 2;
// writing the problem 10 times
function writeProblem(){
    for (var i=1; i<11; i++){
        num1 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+1);
        num2 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+1);
        document.getElementById("top").innerHTML = num1;
        document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML = "+" + num2;
        mathProblem[i] = num1 + num2;
        document.forms["problem"]["answer"].value = "";
}
}
function submitAnswer(){
    var i=0;

    for (i=1;i<11;i++) {
        if (document.forms["problem"]["answer"].value == mathProblem[i]) {
        writeProblem();
        return true;

    }
    else if(isNaN (document.forms["problem"]["answer"].value)){
            alert("This is not a spelling test please use numbers");
            return false;
    }

}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="writeProblem()">
<h2>Practicing Your Pluses!</h2>

<form name="problem">
<input type="text" size="1" name="carry1"><br/> 
<label id="top"></label><br />
<label id="bottom"></label><br /><hr width="60px" align="left"/>
<input type="text" size="3" name="answer">
</form><br/>

<input type="button" onClick="submitAnswer()" value="Submit Answers"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the just demo, How to do the code, but it works with out errors, you need to modify the error code in your side

Answer (score 0):

### [SOLUTION](http://jsbin.com/nihuy/2/edit)

Avoid using `onload`, `onclick` or any inline event or style ([read more](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/))

NOTE: In this solution I'm using [classList](http://caniuse.com/classlist) that aint fully supported.

#### HTML

```
<div>
  <label class="top"></label><br />
  <label class="bottom"></label><br />
  <hr />
  <input class="answer" type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <label class="top"></label><br />
  <label class="bottom"></label><br />
  <hr />
  <input class="answer" type="text">
</div>    
<div>
  <label class="top"></label><br />
  <label class="bottom"></label><br />
  <hr />
  <input class="answer" type="text">
</div>    
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit"/>
```

#### CSS

```
div, input {
  width: 60px;
}
label {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

#### JS

```
var mathProblem = [];
var tops = document.getElementsByClassName('top');
var bottoms = document.getElementsByClassName('bottom');
var answers = document.getElementsByClassName('answer');

function writeProblem(){
  for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
    num1 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+1);
    num2 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+1);
    tops[i].innerHTML = num1;
    bottoms[i].innerHTML = '+' + num2;
    mathProblem[i] = num1 + num2;    
  }
}
window.addEventListener('load', writeProblem);

function submitAnswer(){
  var invalid = document.getElementsByClassName('invalid');
  for(var i=0; i<invalid.length; i++){
    invalid[i].classList.remove('invalid');
  }
  var correct = 0;
  var wrong = 0;
  for (var a=0; a<3; a++) {
    var answer = answers[a];    
    if(isNaN(Number(answer.value))){
      answer.classList.add('invalid');
      alert('This is not a spelling test, please use numbers');      
      return false;
    }
    if(answer.value === ''){
      answer.classList.add('invalid');
      alert('Answer all questions please');
      return false;
    }
    if (Number(answer.value) === mathProblem[a]) {
      correct++;
    }
    else {
      answer.classList.add('invalid');
      wrong++;      
    }
  }
  alert('Correct: ' + correct + '\nWrong: ' + wrong);
}
document.getElementById('submit')
.addEventListener('click', submitAnswer);
```